# Regex to match string separated by dots, can only contain alphanumeric, hypens, underscores, dots

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need a regex that will match the following:

`a.b.c`

`a0.b_.c`

`a.bca._cda.dca-fb`

Notice that it can contain numbers, but the groups are separeted by dots. The characters allowed are `a-zA-z, -, _, 0-9`

The rule is that it cannot start with a number, and it cannot end with a dot. i.e, the regex should **not** match

`0a.b.c`

`a.b.c.d.`

I have come up with a regex, which seems to work on regex101, but not javascript

`([a-zA-Z]+.?)((\w+).)*(\w+)`

[image]`

But does not seem to work in js:

```js
var str = "a.b.c"

if (str.match("([a-zA-Z]+.?)((\w+).)*(\w+)")) {
  console.log("match");
} else {
  console.log("not match");
}

// says not match
```

Comment: Isn't [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51109311/3832970) worth accepting? It looks correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex matches your values if you use anchors to assert the start `^` and the end `$` of the line.

As an alternative you might use:

[`^[a-z][\w-]*(?:\.[\w-]+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/MuA574/1)

This will assert the start of the line `^`, matches a word character `\w` *(which will match `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)* or a hyphen in a character class `[\w-]`.

Then repeat the pattern that will match a dot and the allowed characters in the character class `(?:\.[\w-]+)*` until the end of the line `$`

```js
const strings = [
  "a.b.c",
  "A.b.c",
  "a0.b_.c",
  "a.bca._cda.dca-fb",
  "0a.b.c",
  "a.b.c.d."
];
let pattern = /^[a-z][\w-]*(?:\.[\w-]+)*$/i;

strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s + " ==> " + pattern.test(s));
});
```

If the match should not start with a digit but can start with an underscore or hypen you might use:

[`^[a-z_-][\w-]*(?:\.[\w-]+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/MuA574/2)

Answer (score 1):

Use forward slashes `/` and paste the regex code **between them** from online regex testers, when you use JavaScipt.

Here are, what I've changed in your regex pattern:

- added `^` at the beginning of your regex to match the beginning of the input
- added `$` at the end to match the end of the input
- removed `A-Z` and added the `i` modifier for case-insensitive search (this is optional).

Also, when you use [**regex101**](https://regex101.com/), make sure to **select JavaScript Flavor**, when creating/testing your regex for JavaScript.

```js
var pattern = /^([a-z]+.?)((\w+).)*(\w+)$/i;

// list of strings, that should be matched
var shouldMatch = [
  'a.b.c',
  'a0.b_.c',
  'a.bca._cda.dca-fb'
];

// list of strings, that should not be matched
var shouldNotMatch = [
  '0a.b.c',
  'a.b.c.d.'
];

shouldMatch.forEach(function (string) {
  if (string.match(pattern)) {
    console.log('matched, as it should: "' + string + '"');    
  } else {
    console.log('should\'ve matched, but it didn\'t: "' + string + '"');
  }
});

shouldNotMatch.forEach(function (string) {
  if (!string.match(pattern)) {
    console.log('didn\'t match, as it should: "' + string + '"');
  } else {
    console.log('shouldn\'t have matched, but it did: "' + string + '"');
  }
});
```

[**More on regexes in JavaScript**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Regex seems correct, code doesn't, it says "match" when str = "0a.b.c"

Comment: @KSplitX that is because there is a regex match in the string. Just like how in your regex101 link the line with `0a.b.c` gets matched and the `a.b.c` is highlighted because that is the part that matches.

Comment: @KSplitX, I updated my answer, please, check it out.